# Varnish https caching in apache?

Tags: apache-2.4, https, http, cache, varnish

Is it possible to cache HTTPS traffic with Varnish in apache ?

I have done http caching with varnish and it works fine. But my website is in HTTPS.

So can any body please confirm it ?

Thank you. :-)

Comment: Do you have to use varnish for cache? you can try nuster, https://github.com/jiangwenyuan/nuster, support https/http2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can be done by reverse proxying https requests from port 80 with Apache.
Here's how to do it:
https://bash-prompt.net/guides/apache-varnish/